# Rails - JSON object with an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm able to create and send a JSON object like so:

```
  @mylist << {
    :id => item.id,
    :name => name.id
  }

render :json => { :result => 'success', :mylist => @mylist }
```

That works great. Problem I'm having now is that I need to include users with are 1 or more per item.

```
  @mylist << {
    :id => item.id,
    :name => name.id,
    :users => item.users
  }
```

Where `item.users` contains a list of (user.id, user.name, user.desc).

how do I include an array like users inside a json object? How to build in Rails and then how to parse it with jQuery?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

the code above is inside a:

```
@items.each_with_index do |item, i|
end
```

Perhaps that is a problem here?

Answer (score 1):

If `items.users` is an array then it will be rendered as a JSON array.

When you get the JSON response in your JavaScript, you'll just need to loop over the array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.users.length; i++) {
    //do something with data.users[i]
}
```

where `data` is the JSON data returned from the Ajax call.

Comment: Problem with item.users is it includes ALL the fields which I don't want. Very inefficient. How can I specify which fields I want?

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine out of the box. Arrays inside arrays is no problem. Rails walks down your objects and tries to convert them to simple objects like hashes, arrays, strings and numbers. ActiveRecord objects will turn all their attributes into a hash when you convert it to JSON. If `item.users` is an array of ActiveRecord instances, than your example will automatically work. You can retrieve them in Javascript exactly as you would walk through a hash and array in Ruby. So something like:

```
response['mylist']['users'][0]['name']
```

**Edit**

To limit the fields in the user, add a method to the user class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def as_json(*)
    { :name => name, :desc => desc }
  end
end
```

Comment: How to I set the array to the JSON object above, that's where I'm stuck

Comment: if I try with item.users, it includes users but with all fields. How do I select which fields I need. Also then everything after the users is broken: ,{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],"result":"success"}

Comment: @Iain, thanks for the update. I'm banging my head on the wall. But I'm not sure how that edit solves the issue?

Comment: I don't need to limit the fields. I need to make a hash @newhash << { :users => item.users} where item.users is an array. that's what is breaking. thxs

Comment: hmmm... you commented it on SkillDricks answer. Anyhow, if the json is broken try `item.users.to_a`